# Why is this error showing while working on Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, create-table, alter-table

Code :-

```
CREATE TABLE dbo_urban(
    T_Date    date      ,
    Latest_User_Id   varchar (100));
ALTER TABLE dbo_urban ALTER Latest_User_Id  SET DEFAULT " ";
```

Above written code is what table looks like. There is no data in the table.

ERROR :-

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'DEFAULT' expecting NOT(line 1, pos 70)

== SQL ==
ALTER TABLE dbo_trn_billwise_itemwise_urban ALTER Latest_User_Id  SET DEFAULT, " "
----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Databricks has its own sql syntax, it does not follow mysql's syntax.

Comment: Please consider adding more context directly to the answer and not only the tags. This helps a lot

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the [documentation for ALTER TABLE command](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html) on Databricks you'll see that it doesn't support setting the default value. It's not supported in CREATE TABLE as well.

If you need to set default value for missing data, then you need to do it within the code.

Comment: Show how you are doing it now - it’s too broad question